# Convert Seconds to Hours in R

Tags: r

I have a column that is in seconds and I want to convert it into hours.  I preferably want the hours into a decimal format such as 8.5 hours instead of hours and minutes in separate columns. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `your_data$hours = your_data$your_seconds_column / 60 / 60` should do it. If you need more help, please post a reproducible example with expected output.

Comment: Thanks Gregor!  Apologies this is my first time posting.  I will do that next time

Answer (score 1):

Here are two methods.  Both also work if x is a vector.  The first uses the fact that there are 3600 seconds in an hour.  The second is longer but does not use special numbers.  No packages are used.

```
x <- 30600 # test data

x / 3600
## [1] 8.5

as.numeric(as.difftime(x, units = "secs"), units = "hours")
## [1] 8.5
```